# How do I check if a remote website has a custom 404 page or not in php?

Tags: php, http, testing, http-status-code-404

I am trying to create some basic SEO testing tool, now I don't know how do I check if a remote website has a 404 page or not in php ? Something like this

```
<?php  
  $info404 = "";
  if(404 custome page exists){
    $info404 = " Good ";
  } 
  else{
    $info404 = " Bad ";
  }
?>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can user curl_getinfo function

Comment: All the answers I found here mainly relate to whether a specific ulr has a response of 200 or 400. Could I ask you to write me that piece of code or give me a link if you know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602631/how-to-check-if-a-url-exists-or-not-error-404-using-php and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php/17832110 check out this

Comment: the answers to this topic are based on whether a particular link has a response of 200 or 400. But i I need to know if the default url given by user has a custome 404 page.

Comment: Why does it matter? How do you define "custom"? (serious question)

Comment: The point is that users will generally type a valid URL into a input field. The code need to pick that url  given by user ( exp. www.myworkingsite.com ) and test does that url have a custome 404 page or not.  Like on this web site: https://www.seowebpageanalyzer.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to check status code. of any URL.

```
 public function callAPI($method, $url, $data = false, $headers = [])
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    if (count($headers) > 0) {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    }

    switch ($method) {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data) {
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            }

            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            break;
        default:
            if ($data) {
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
            }

    }

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($curl);

    return [
        'result' => $result,
        'statusCode' => $httpcode,
    ];
}
//this will send request to given URL and function will return response code and whole response.
$response = callAPI("GET",$url);
$responseCode = $response["statusCode"];
if($responseCode == '404'){
    echo "404 not found";
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new with PHP, can you describe what this does or add comments to the code. I would be very grateful.

Comment: @Zika sure, I have added and example also added a comment what will this code do.

Comment: This function works with the initial assumption that the url entered is not good. The point is that users will generally type a valid URL. The point is to test that valid with a status of 200 entered to test exm. www.myworkingsite.com have a custome 404 page or not.

Comment: @Zika Ohkay, Let me check for that.